# Is there an icon for LinkedIn in LaTeX?

Tags: symbols, fontawesome

I am trying to create my resume in LaTeX and I want to add a LinkedIn symbol for my profile. I am using the FontAwesome template but it does not work for LinkedIn. I am new to LaTeX so any help is much appreciated.

```
 \documentclass[9pt]{developercv}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.35\textwidth}
    \vspace{-\baselineskip}
        \icon{Globe}{12}{\href{https://glitch.com/}{name}}\\
        \icon{Github}{12}{\href{https://github.com/}{name}}\\
        \icon{LinkedIn}{12}{\href{https://www.linkedin.com}{name lastname}}\\
   \end{minipage}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX Stack Exchange! Both the fontawesome and the newer fontawesome5 packages provide a LinkedIn icon, but `\icon` is neither a standard LaTeX command nor provided by these packages. So to answer your question, we will need to know what packages and which documentclass you use. The best way to get an answer is often to provide a [*minimal* working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) which starts with `\documentclass{...}` and ends with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I just edited my code with the document class. I am using an overleaf resume template so the FontAwesome template has been used in the developercv.cls file.

Comment: Then we also need access to the `developercv.cls` file. It is not a standard LaTeX class and "the FontAwesome template" is not really specific enough given a huge number of templates on overleaf.

Comment: hi there, `fontawesome` makes available `\faLinkedinSquare` and `\faLinkedin`. You can maybe have a look to the `moderncv` class, that uses them, and compare it with your implementation: https://github.com/xdanaux/moderncv/blob/master/moderncviconsawesome.sty
BTW, I highly recommend `moderncv`: give it a try before committing to write a whole class from scratch

Answer (score 4):

The name for the LinkedIn icon is

```
Linkedin
```

Ask the developer of `fontawesome` why.

```latex
\documentclass[9pt]{developercv}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\icon{Globe}{12}{\href{https://example.com/@name}{name}}\\
\icon{Github}{12}{\href{https://example.com/name}{name}}\\
\icon{Linkedin}{12}{\href{https://example.com/in/name-123456/}{Name Surname}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I removed your personal data in the code, you should do it as well in your question.

Comment: I used LinkedinSquare and it worked for me. Also took your advice on removing my personal information :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes.
At first you have to use fontawesome5 package:

```
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
```

and then use LinkedIn icon where ever you want like this:

```
\faIcon{linkedin}
```

or

```
\faIcon{linkedin-in}
```

Comment: this worked for me 2023 when updating an old style file